# Allow comment on rollback?

Tags: feature-request, rollbacks, edit-summary

When editing you can enter a one-line <strike>comment</strike> "Edit Summary".

It would be nice if a comment could be left when rolling back.  Can this be added at some time?

Comment: Seems like a decent idea to me. +1

Comment: Lots of comments will be generated during a rollback war, eh

Comment: @Sathya A comment might end a rollback war. :-)